# Restrict a specific letter/number in the first input in the edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

Currently i have edittext that the user requires to input his/her mobile number.

What i need to do is to restrict the user to input "0" and only allow "9" to be first input in the edittext
for the example:

when the user tries to input "0" in the edittext and it is the current first number in the edittext, it shouldn't be allowed.

input that can only be accept is :
9351312351, 9313151231.
the other number like
0931231551, 02312512312 shouldn't be allow.

My current idea is something like this in the textwatcher:

```
@Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
 if (!mMobileNumberNoEditText.getText().toString().substring(0,0).equals("9")) {
                mMobileNumberNoEditText.setText("");
            }
}
```

Currently causing an error the moment i input any number.
The logcat shows nothing. it just freeze and stopped working.

Comment: its looks good..then what is your question?

Comment: what is the problem with that code?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko edited the post, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below by checking length

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
String number = number.toString()
    if(number.startsWith("0"))
    {
        mMobileNumberNoEditText.setText("");
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't know that there's something like this. Thanks!